# wxPython - titled border

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, titled-border

I have searched `wxPython` documentation and can't find any way to make a titled border on a panel. I need a border like the one on `wx.RadioBox` have with caption in it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using one of [wx.StaticBox](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_static_box.html) or [wx.StaticBoxSizer](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_static_box_sizer.html).